# jquery-ui, added tab, cannot switch to older tab via text link on new tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

I have spent many hours researching this problem to no avail.  I have a simple page with 3 tabs. Tab #1 has a button to add a new tab (tab #4).  Tab #2 has a hyperlink to switch to tab #3 which works fine (also get console message).  After adding tab #4 (index=3), via button, which includes a hyperlink to switch to tab #3, the hyperlink on tab #4 is not functional nor is there a console message.

```js
function addTab4() {
    $("#btnAdd").attr("disabled","disabled").text("tab 4 added");
    
    $("#tabs").find(".ui-tabs-nav").append('<li><a href="#tabs_4">4</a></li>');
    
 $("#tabs").append("<div id='tabs_4'></div>");

    $("#tabs_4").html("<a id='selectTab3' href='#tabs_3'>goto tab 3</a>"); // doesn't switch to tab 3
    
 $("#tabs").tabs("enable");
    $("#tabs").tabs("refresh");
    
    return false;
    
};



$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#tabs").tabs();
 $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", 0);
    
    $("a#selectTab3").click(function() {//works from an original tab, not added tab
     console.log("a#selectTab3 clicked");
        $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", 2);
    });
    
 $("#btnAdd").click(function() {
  addTab4();
 });    
 
});
```

```html
<div id="tabs">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#tabs_1">1</a></li>  
  <li><a href="#tabs_2">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tabs_3">3</a></li>
 </ul>
 <div id="tabs_1">
  One<br>
    
        <button id="btnAdd">Add Tab 4</button>
    
 </div>
 <div id="tabs_2">
  Two<br>
  <a id="selectTab3" href="#tabs_3">goto tab 3</a> <!-- works  -->
 </div>
 <div id="tabs_3">
  Three
 </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you have dynamically generated the anchor element. So, the `click` event you have designated for the anchor will not work for the newly created event. To tackle that you need to [Understand & Use Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). So instead of the previous event handler use this instead and you will be fine,

```
 $(document).on("click","a.selectTab3",function() {
        console.log("a#selectTab3 clicked");
        $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", 2);
    });
```

#### And here is the [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4axwh43o/)

**P.S**

You are attempting to use multiple id with the same name which is a very bad practice as `id` must be unique in the DOM. So, I have changed it to instead use `class`.

Comment: Excellent!  Works great. I appreciate the link to understanding event delegation.  As to multiple `ID`s,  that was just a simple mistake of not paying enough attention. Thanks very much,